# Inserir barra de progresso com php - Bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, progress-bar

É possível inserir uma barra de progresso usando [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) referente a quantidade de dados inseridos em uma determinada tabela no banco de dados?

Ex:
Caso eu tenha 100 registros a barra iria progredindo até chegar o numero 100.

Comment: procuras uma progress-bar e clocas. depois o código fazes o count dos registos da base de dados

Comment: Integre com o banco e faça: http://jsfiddle.net/yf8eq9vx/

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293588/campo-porcentagem-em-html/293590#293590

Answer (score 1):

Caso você já tenha o css do bootstrap você pode usar o `mysqli_num_row` para pegar o numero de linhas inserida na tabela